# Leaf nodes and paths in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph in Neo4J that looks like this:

```
(a {flag:any})<- (many, 0 or more) <-(b {flag:true})<- (many, 0 or more) <-(c {flag: any})
-OR-
(a {flag:any})<- (many, 0 or more) <-(d)
-OR-
(a {flag:any})
```

Where a, b, c, and d all have the same type, and the relations are also the same. All the nodes have **flag:false** except where noted. Of course the real graph is a tree, not a vine.

In short, every path should begin with **a** and end with the *first* flag=true node, or should begin with **a** and get all children down to the leaf of the tree. Per the last example, **a** doesn't have to have any children - it can be a root and a leaf. Finally, in the first case, we'll never pull in **c**. **b** stops the traversal.

How can I write this query?

I have gotten it to work with a path and several unwind/collect statements that are basically horse****, lol. I want a better query, but I am so confused now it is not going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should return all 3 kinds of paths. I assume that all relevant nodes are labeled `Foo`, and all relevant relationships have the `BAR` type.

The first term of the `WHERE` clause looks for paths (of length 0 or more, because of the variable-length relationship pattern used in the `MATCH` clasue) that end in a node with a `true` flag with no `true` flags earlier in the path (except for possibly the starting node). The second term looks for paths (of length 0 or more) ending with a leaf node, where no nodes (except for possibly the starting node) have a `true` flag.

```
MATCH p=(a:Foo)<-[:BAR*0..]-(b:Foo)
WHERE
  (b.flag AND NONE(x IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE x.flag)) OR
  ((NOT (b)<-[:BAR]-()) AND NONE(y IN NODES(p)[1..] WHERE y.flag))
RETURN p;
```

NOTE: Variable-length relationship patterns with no upper bound (like `[:BAR*0..]`) can be very expensive, and can take a very long time or cause an out of memory error. So, you may need to specify a reasonable upper bound (for example, `[:BAR*0..5]`).

Comment: Thanks Sam. The thing here I didn't really know what the `[1..-1]` bit on the collections.

Comment: In this case, it generates a new list consisting of the second through next-to-last nodes in `p`. See [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-lists-general) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this query as the `UNION` of the two cases:

```
MATCH shortestPath((a)<-[:REL_TYPE*1..]-(end:Label {flag: true}))
RETURN a, end
UNION
MATCH (a)<-[:REL_TYPE*0..]-(end:Label)
WHERE NOT (end)<-[:REL_TYPE]-()
RETURN a, end
```

Let's break it down:

1. To express that we only want to traverse until the *first* flag is true, we use [`shortestPath`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/).
2. To express that we want to traverse down to the leaf, we use the following formalisation: a node is a leaf if it has no relationships that could be continued, captured by a [`WHERE NOT` filter on patterns](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#filter-on-patterns-using-not).

This should give an idea of the basic ideas to use for such queries -- please provide some feedback so that I can refine the answer.